# How does python iterator for list actually works?

Tags: python, list, iterator

Let's say we have the following list and we are creating an iterator for it:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
itr = iter(lst)
```

Next lets say we are changing our list with completely different values:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And if I we run the following loop:

```
for x in itr:
   print x
```

We will get `'1,2,3'`. But why? As far as I understand, iterator doesn't copy all values from iterating object. At least iterator for list from three elements has the same size as a list of 100000 elements. `sys.getsizeof(i)` returns `64`. How can iterator be so small by size and keep 'old' values of list?

Comment: You haven't changed the list, you've created a new, completely unrelated one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator itself contains a reference to the list. Since `lst` is rebound instead of mutated, this reference does not change.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> itr = iter(lst)
>>> lst[:] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for x in itr:
...   print x
... 
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 3):

The iterator references a list object not a name. So *reassigning* the name `lst` to another object does not affect the iterator in anyway; names are bound to objects, and refer to objects, but the names are not the object themselves.

You can get a snoop of the object the iterator is referencing with [`gc.get_referents`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.get_referents):

```
>>> import gc
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> itr = iter(lst) # return an iterator for the list
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c'] # Bind name lst to another object
>>> gc.get_referents(itr)[0]
[1, 2, 3]
```

As you'll notice, the iterator is still referring to the first list object.

---

The following reference will help you learn more about *names and binding* in Python:

[Execution model - Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Python's object reference system. The variable names do not really have a deep relationship with the actual object stored in memory.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
itr = iter(lst)  # iter object now points to the list pointed to by lst

print(next(itr))  # prints 1

# Both `lst` and `lst1` now refer to the same list
lst1 = lst

# `lst` now points to a new list, while `lst1` still points to the original list.
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(next(itr))  # prints 2

lst.append(4)
lst1.append(5)  # here the list pointed to by `itr` is updated

for i in itr:
    print(i)  # prints 3, 5
```

**TL;DR**: Python variable names are just tags, that refer to some object in space.
When you call `iter` on the `list` named `lst`, the iterator object points to the actual object, and not the name `lst`.

If you can modify the original object, by calling `append`, `extend`, `pop`, `remove`, etc, the iterator's output will be affected. But when you assign a new value to `lst`, a new object is created (if it didn't previously exist), and `lst` simply starts pointing to that new object.

The garbage collector will delete the original object if no other object is pointing to it (`itr` is pointing to it in this case, so the original object won't be deleted yet).

http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/

Extra:

```
lst1.extend([6, 7, 8])
next(itr)    # raises StopIteration
```

This doesn't have anything to do with object referencing, the iterator just stores internally that it has iterated the complete list.